# Passing parameter as parameter in Fortran-90?

Tags: parameters, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran, select-case

Suppose I have a subroutine:

```
subroutine foo(x, Nx)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(IN) :: x
    integer, intent(IN) :: Nx

    select case(x)
        case (1)
            write(*,*) "Minimum value"
        case (Nx)
            write(*,*) "Maximum value"
        case default
            write(*,*) "Somewhere in-between"
    end select
end subroutine foo
```

Suppose my driver looks like this:

```
program main
    implicit none

    interface
        subroutine foo(x,Nx)
            integer, intent(IN)  :: x
            integer, intent(IN)  :: Nx
        end subroutine foo
    end interface

    integer, parameter :: Nx = 100
    integer :: x

    call foo(20, Nx)

end program main
```

The above program will not compile because in the subroutine, `case (Nx)` is invalid. Specifically, ifort 16 gives the following error:

> error #6601: In a CASE statement, the case-value must be a constant expression.

In other words, even though Nx is *effectively* declared as a subroutine constant via `intent(IN)`, it needs to be either a literal constant or `parameter` of type `integer`.

Are there any ways to make the case statement accept `Nx` as the constant parameter we know it to be? Is there some way to declare `Nx` to be a passed-in `parameter`?

I realize that in this simple, short example, an if-then-elseif-else-end block would suffice, but then I wouldn't know the answer to this question. :-)

Comment: FYI you're missing an end quote after `"Maximum value`. And possibly a `::` in `integer, parameter Nx`.

Comment: Could you define a module that would contain your parameter along with the subroutine, and if so, would that help?:)

Comment: By the way, you say "In other words, even though Nx is effectively declared as a subroutine constant via `intent(IN)`...". I think the problem is that fortran needs to know the `case` values *during compile-time*, so being a subroutine constant is not enough. Otherwise I don't see why it would hurt the compiler to find out the values on-the-fly, without having to prescribe any constant attribute.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Other languages don't require switch/select/case constructs to have compile-time constants (they often aren't!). I acknowledge language specifications, but I think this is something that is more of a bug than a feature. (But what do I know?! :-) ) I think the module idea might work (Personal ToDo: test this), though it wouldn't be elegant for this purpose.

Comment: The point is that the case construct can typically be implemented as a jump-table and not as if-else branches. C has the same property.

Answer (score 5):

Just use an if statement. A subroutine argument (which you call parameter) is certainly not a parameter (named constant). The `intent(in)` doesn't make it *effectively* a parameter, it is just a promise you will not change it, but there are ways to circumvent that. The case statement needs a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 3):

You ask whether there is a way to "accept *Nx* as the constant parameter we know it to be?".  We *don't* know that *Nx* forms a constant expression, and we indeed know that it *doesn't*.

The only way for `Nx` to be a constant expression is for `Nx` to be a named constant.  Being a named constant is incompatible with being a dummy argument, even one which is argument associated, with `intent(in)` or no `intent` attribute, with a named constant.

Conceptually, the subroutine `foo` is an external procedure as far as the main program is concerned (there's an interface block).  This means that one would expect it to be compiled as a stand-alone thing, being linked in at that later stage.  It should be valid regardless of its ultimate use.  [That said, even when it isn't an external procedure the first part still holds as far as the language specification goes.]

Naturally, there are other ways to have `Nx` a named constant in the subroutine if you don't want to rewrite this using an `if` construct.