# Fortran Define Parameter from variable

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I wish to define a parameter that will not change in my module from a input variable.

**Example**

```
module foo
    contains
    subroutine function1(external_var)
       integer, parameter x = external_var(1)
       write(*,*) x
    end subroutine function1
end module foo
```

However, this gives an error.

```
PGF90-S-0087-Non-constant expression where constant expression required
```

Comment: A "parameter" (named constant) must be known "at compile time".  However, from your code fragment there's no obvious reason why you would need `x` to be a named constant.  Can you explain more about what you want to do with the set-once-by-input variable?  If so, we can give you alternative approaches to consider,

Comment: Note also that just because the actual argument associated with `external_var` may be a constant doesn't mean that [`external_var` itself is](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32553490/3157076).

Comment: the array external_var is read from a file and fixed, I want to assign it to a parameter that will not change. I was having some trouble in my code, where arrays were being wiped and wanted to prevent them from being altered.

Comment: Protected might go some of the way to what the OP wants - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020460/protected-global-variables-in-fortran